# Passing encoded * in REST query parameter

Tags: java, regex, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a REST GET service which takes in query parameters like first name and last name and will return the results based on that. The service has to support both exact and wildcard search. If a wildcard search is to be triggered the client can pass * as wild card entry. For e.g he wants all users whose name starts with Mur, he will pass the firstName=mur*.

Since one cannot pass * in the query string, they have to pass the URL encoded value of * which is %2A. The problem is even if the encoded value is sent the service throws the error

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0

I do pass : (%3A) or & (%26) and it works successfully, why the * character is not being read.

I am testing the service with POSTMAN rest cleint and also SOAPUI and both throws the same error. Is this a problem with Spring?

Thanks for any help!!
Tatha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, my guess is you are using (knowingly or not) one of the regex functions, such as any method in `Pattern`, `String.matches()`, `String.replaceAll()` or similar to check if a name matches the pattern passed as parameter.

As a result, your pattern must follow Regular Expression syntax, in which "any name starting with `mur`" should be expressed as `mur.*` (note the dot), not `mur*`. If you pass the asterisk `*` as the only character, it results in an invalid Regular Expression, hence the error.

The error message `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0` clearly sugegsts we are dealing with a Regular Expression and that the offending asterisk is the firs character in the string (index 0).

So, if the above is true, you either have to pass the query in regex syntax, or change the way you match names to the pattern to match the syntax you want to use.

Comment: Thanks @michał-kosmulski for the response. I was using String.replaceAll("*") to replace the wildcard character to blank space and call a wildcard search on LDAP. I will check by with .*. Thanks a Ton!!!